# `Store Named Attribute` Values not as expected

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm using a `Store Named Attribute` to store a value of `1.0`.
Weird thing is I also get values like `0.319`, `0.588` etc.

[image]

If I change the value from `1.0` to `2.0` then magically those other weird values change too.

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *Bevel* modifier which creates new geometry and assigns data to the attribute by interpolating surrounding old geometry. When you mute the *Bevel* modifier, and add another *Store Named Attribute* to capture the selection used, you can see all values are as expected:

[image]